# My tkinter button only works half the time

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to learn to code, but my button "BuyRobot" only works sometimes and i dont know why. I want to be able to press the button multiple times, and for the label that show how many i have to be updated (labelRobot) I think it has something to do with being in a loop, but i have tried putting it outside the loop but i cant seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly apreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time

n=1
Robot=0
def BuyRobotCommand():
    global n
    global Robot
    Robot+=n


vindu=Tk()
vindu.title("Robo Wood")
geo="1920x1080"
vindu.geometry("1920x1080")


WoodCurrency=99
Money=0
WoodCutter=0


fontStyle=tkFont.Font(size=20)
#labelWood=Label(vindu, text="You have "+str(WoodCurrency)+" wood", font=fontStyle).place(x=(1920/2)-100, y=100)
#BuyRobot=Button(vindu, text="Kjøp en robot", font=fontStyle, command=BuyRobotCommand(1)).place(x=300, y=300)

true=1
delay=0.1
while true:
    vindu.update()

    #Fikser penger, og trær
    WoodCurrency+=1*Robot
    labelWood=Label(vindu, text="You have "+str(WoodCurrency)+" wood", font=fontStyle).place(x=(1920/2)-100, y=80)
    if WoodCurrency>0:
        Money+=1
        WoodCurrency-=1
    labelMoney=Label(vindu, text="You have "+str(Money)+" money", font=fontStyle).place(x=(1920/2)-100, y=130)


    BuyRobot=Button(vindu, text="Kjøp en robot", font=fontStyle, command=BuyRobotCommand).place(x=300, y=300)
    labelRobot=Label(vindu, text="You have "+str(Robot)+" wood cutter robots", font=fontStyle).place(x=500, y=300)



    time.sleep(delay)


vindu.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you don't need the `while` loop, but instead should rely on the `vindu.mainloop()`. Either way I think that creating your `Label`s and `Button` should occur before the loop.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you expect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you have to use [`window.after()`](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22870/-after--).

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time

n=1
Robot=0
def BuyRobotCommand():
    global n
    global Robot
    Robot+=1

vindu=Tk()
vindu.title("Robo Wood")
geo="1920x1080"
vindu.geometry("1920x1080")


WoodCurrency=99
Money=0
WoodCutter=0


fontStyle=tkFont.Font(size=20)
labelMoney=Label(vindu, text="You have "+str(Money)+" money", font=fontStyle).place(x=(1920/2)-100, y=130)


BuyRobot=Button(vindu, text="Kjøp en robot", font=fontStyle, command=BuyRobotCommand).place(x=300, y=300)


#labelWood=Label(vindu, text="You have "+str(WoodCurrency)+" wood", font=fontStyle).place(x=(1920/2)-100, y=100)
#BuyRobot=Button(vindu, text="Kjøp en robot", font=fontStyle, command=BuyRobotCommand(1)).place(x=300, y=300)

true=1
delay=0.1
labelRobot=Label(vindu, text="You have "+str(Robot)+" wood cutter robots", font=fontStyle)
labelRobot.place(x=500, y=300)
def main_loop():
    global delay, true, WoodCurrency, Money, WoodCutter

    #Fikser penger, og trær
    WoodCurrency+=1*Robot
    if WoodCurrency>0:
        Money+=1
        WoodCurrency-=1

    labelRobot.configure(text = "You have "+str(Robot)+" wood cutter robots")

    vindu.after(100, main_loop)
main_loop()


vindu.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Won't the `main_loop()` function just keep on creating new `Label`s?

Comment: Let me test, one minute. When I ran, it didn't do that.

Comment: All these widgets should be created once and then they can be updated many times after.

Comment: @quamrana It should technically, but when you run the program, it doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Either, way, I'll use configure().

Comment: I'm sure if you make the `x` and `y` be different you will see more labels.

Comment: But the labels look different, so it will look like they overlap.

Comment: Your `labelMoney` has a `None` value, this will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

How about using StringVars for the labels *textvariable*?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time

n = 1
Robot = 0
def BuyRobotCommand():
    global n
    global Robot
    Robot += n

vindu = Tk()
vindu.title("Robo Wood")
geo="1920x1080"
vindu.geometry(geo)

WoodCurrency = 99
WoodCurrencyLabel = StringVar(master=vindu,value="You have " + str(WoodCurrency) + " wood")
Money = 0
MoneyLabel = StringVar(master=vindu,value="You have " + str(Money) + " money")
WoodCutter = 0
RobotLabel = StringVar(master=vindu,value="You have " + str(Robot) + " wood cutter robots")

fontStyle=tkFont.Font(size=20)
labelWood=Label(vindu, textvariable=WoodCurrencyLabel, font=fontStyle).place(x=(1920/2)-100, y=100)
labelMoney=Label(vindu, textvariable=MoneyLabel, font=fontStyle).place(x=(1920/2)-100, y=130)
BuyRobot=Button(vindu, text="Kjøp en robot", font=fontStyle, command=BuyRobotCommand).place(x=300, y=300)
labelRobot=Label(vindu, textvariable=RobotLabel, font=fontStyle).place(x=500, y=300)
delay=0.1

while True:
    vindu.update()
    #Fikser penger, og trær
    WoodCurrency += 1 * Robot
    if WoodCurrency>0:
        Money += 1
        WoodCurrency -= 1
    WoodCurrencyLabel.set("You have " + str(WoodCurrency) + " wood")
    MoneyLabel.set("You have " + str(Money) + " money")
    RobotLabel.set("You have " + str(Robot) + " wood cutter robots")
    time.sleep(delay)

vindu.mainloop()
```

That way you can update your variables without needing to recreate the label widget to display it every time.